# How to find View frame for IPhone 5 and IPhone 6 and IPhone 6+

Tags: ios

I have an application where I am adding one view with certain frame  programmatically, it is okay for iphone4 (320 * 480) but How can I calculate frame size for IPhone5 and IPhone6 resolutions with given autoresizingmask value , Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show me your view. ? It could be perfect for all devices, if you give all margins and flexible width & height as AutoResizingmask for the view.

Comment: iam adding programatically, not in xib

Comment: this my code , if(IPhone_4) {
     view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 320, 100)];
    }
    if(IPhone_5) {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, ?, ?)];
    }
    if(IPhone_6) {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, ?, ?)];
    }

Comment: Use [auto layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)

Comment: its working , i forgot to give autoresizing mask , thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to give autoresizing mask. Adding that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

To create programmatically you can use screen bounds to calculate size of the device

```
 CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

> screenRect.size.height == 667 width = 375// iphone6
>
> screenRect.size.height == 736 width 414 // iphone 6+
>
> screenRect.size.height == 568 width 320 // iphone 5